# How to enable HTTPS in Kubernetes NGINX Ingress Controller on a private network?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I want to configure Ingress for Internal HTTPS Load Balancing on a private network. So when a user try to access https://192.168.1.1 SSL offloading has to be done in ingress.

How can I implement that? Is there a way to enable HTTPS in Kubernetes NGINX Ingress Controller on a private network? It could be done when a host is defined in the rules but is it possible to implement that somehow without defining any host?

The below one does now work:

```
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: my-secret
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: my-cluster-service
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Did you see [Azure documentation - Create an ingress controller to an internal virtual network in Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-internal-ip) ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have cheked the link but it does not provide any solution to my problem.